# How to migrate a java application running in Apache Tomcat 5 to Apache Tomcat 7?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Previously I did an web application in spring MVC on Apache Tomcat 5 and i wanted to migrate it to Apache Tomcat 7 now . May I know the steps for the migration.

Can anyone help me out ?

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: Most likely it will just work.  Also consider the newest Tomcat.

Comment: I have deployed the war file in webapps folder and when I tried to run it  shows "SEVERE: Error listenerStart"

Comment: Build the project using tomcat7. Then deploy

Answer (score 0):

It should be straight forward. Please keep the following points in mind before you migrate.

- Apache Tomcat 7 requires Java 6 or later.
- Apache Tomcat 7 supports    Java Servlet 3.0, Java Server Pages 2.2,
  Expression Language 2.2 and    WebSocket 1.1

In JSP pages that use wildcard import syntax the new classes added in Servlet API may conflict with ones in web applications. For example, if package "a" contains class Part, the following JSP page will cease to compile in Tomcat 7:

```
<%@page import="a.*"%>
<% Part page = new Part(); %>
```

That happens because implicit import of javax.servlet.http.* and explicit import of a.* will provide conflicting definitions of class Part that was added in Servlet 3.0. The solution is to use explicit import, import="a.Part".

- All configuration options that use regular expression now require a
  single regular expression (using java.util.regex) rather than a list
  of comma-separated or semi-colon-separated expressions.

[Please refer here for more information about migrating to Tomcat 7](https://tomcat.apache.org/migration-7.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a .war file of your project, then its too easy to deploy application on Tomcat 7. You need to just open you apache tomcat 7 admin console and deploy .war file and it should work fine.